# What happened to Darren Vogel in CSI:Miami?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, csi-miami

In the S10E19 of [CSI:Miami](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0313043/), Darren Vogel is also in the car which was driven by Sam (in the final segment of the episode). But after the accident, we see Sam is carried away by Horatio and Delko. Eddie Coster is shown dead.

But only one dead body is taken away from the scene (which definitely has to be of Eddie's). So it makes a total of two people taken out from the scene.

But there were three people in the car. What happened to Darren (the third person)?

Comment: Seems nobody knows what happened to the mysterious lawyer. :O

Comment: Darren Darren. Where are you?

Comment: It also doesn't help that the primary user base is either asleep or just waking up in a few hours :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching the episode for several times, I finally managed to find him!!

Darren is also taken away from the accident scene. The reason he isn't noted is that the camera stays on him only a few seconds. He is alive when he is taken away, with an oxygen mask attached to his mouth.

I really thought this was a odd mistake. But finally there he was!